# Problem importing Jython in modular project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jython

I wanted to use the Jython library in my Java application because I need my app to use Python. In the maven `pom.xml` file I added the Jython dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.python</groupId>
        <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I observed that without using modules Jython works fine. Specifically, the following method works flawlessly in a basic project I created:

```
import org.python.core.PyObject;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter

public void pyth() {
        try (PythonInterpreter pyInterp = new PythonInterpreter()) {
            pyInterp.exec("x = 10+10");
            PyObject x = pyInterp.get("x");
            System.out.println(x.asInt());
        }
    }
```

However when I introduce module declarations in the project, Jython packages fail to be imported. I get the following error as soon as I add a `module-info.java` file:

`Package 'org.python.core' is declared in module 'org.objectweb.asm', which does not export it to module`

IntelliJ suggests me to add the following line in the Module Compiler Options

```
--add-exports org.objectweb.asm/org.python.util=<module-name>
--add-exports org.objectweb.asm/org.python.core=<module-name>
```

My question is, is there any other way to circumvent IntelliJ's suggested solution? Perhaps a missing dependency or plugin in the `pom.xml` file or a missing declaration in `module-info.java`?